# how to hide featured image from SOME posts

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to hide the featured image from SOME posts?

My blog is [cur-mudg-eon.com](http://www.cur-mudg-eon.com) and if you look at the most recent post (on the homepage) titled "Confucius Says..." you'll see that I've used the featured image and it shows some excerpt text.  When you click on the title or pic it takes you to the post which shows the cartoon I wish to display, and the featured image that I want to hide/remove.

I only want to do this on some posts, but I would like to be able to keep the featured image on the homepage.

Is this possible?

### **EDIT:**

[Pastebin File](http://pastebin.com/H71TAYZ4) as requested.

Based on Chris Herberts answer where would I add his code to this code found in my single.php file:

```
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
        echo '<figure class="featured-thumbnail"><span class="img-wrap">'; the_post_thumbnail(); echo '</span></figure>';
        }
      ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
        echo '<figure class="featured-thumbnail large"><span class="img-wrap"><span class="f-thumb-wrap">'; the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail-xl'); echo '</span></span></figure>';
        }
      ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way to do this that does not depend on them all being in the same category is to use a [Custom Field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Custom_Fields).

You would set a custom field for the post for which you would hide the featured image - in the image below I'm using "hide_featured_image" and "yes", as the key and value, respectively.

[image]

Then you would check to see if the "hide_featured_image" field is set to "yes" when calling calling the function to show the featured image.  Here's an example:

```
$shouldHideFeaturedImage = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hide_featured_image', true);

if ( $shouldHideFeaturedImage != 'yes' ) {
 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail('medium'); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: For anyone that is new to WP (like myself) you will need to "unhide" the Custom Fields.  To do this you need to click on "Posts", then click on "edit" for the post in question.  Once you're in the edit screen for the post, click on the "Screen Options" tab in the upper right corner and make sure the "Custom Fields" box has a check mark in it.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  If you could help me add your code to the code I just added to my original post it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a little more of the page's code?  The snippet you posted is missing a closing ?> tag and I don't want to mess anything up.

Comment: Actually post the whole page on pastebin or something.  There are brackets that don't match up in your snippet.

Comment: Never seen pastebin before.... I like it.  [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/H71TAYZ4)

Comment: Make sure you back up the old version of single.php first

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks again for all your help Chris.

Answer (score 2):

If all those posts are in the same categories, you can do something like this.

On your theme files, under the file single.php there should be something similar to this:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail('medium'); 
}
```

change it to something like:

```
if ( !in_category( array( 'category1', 'category2', 'etc' ) )) {
 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail('medium'); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This looks like it would work great, but the posts might not always be in the same category.  Just in case another individual is looking at this option, would it be possible to add extra "if" statements for additional categories?

Comment: Sure. I edited the response so it's possible to add an array with the category names.